# Jquery on page scroll misbehaving in firefox but works in chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll

Below is my website,
http://kmg.makingconnection.co.uk/impressiveOne/

It's working absolutely fine in chrome but not in Firefox.
header is fixed and on clicking menu, it scrolls to the location on the same page.

BUT when in Firefox, it does the same job but when it tries to stop at location it suddenly bumps.

Please help
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-98
    }, 900, 'easeOutQuad', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
```

You are trying to jump to location twice. Once with animate and other one with `window.location.hash = target`
Removing this one should solve your problem

Comment: Oh my God! Un beleivable, it worked. I spent whole day figuring this out :(. Thank you so much Icepick. Kindly let me know how to select it as a correct answer and vote you up e.t.c. i am not familiar.